# SQL Server : filling in sparse values

Tags: sql-server

Need help with SQL Server; what will be the easiest way to update the missing begin and end inventory values? Values shown are verified numbers for that week.

```
+------+--------+-------+----------+-----+
| Week | ItemNr | Begin | Increase | End |
+------+--------+-------+----------+-----+
|    1 |   1001 |   100 |      -10 |  90 |
|    2 |   1001 |       |        0 |     |
|    3 |   1001 |    90 |        0 |  90 |
|    4 |   1001 |       |       20 |     |
|    5 |   1001 |       |      100 |     |
|    6 |   1001 |       |      -20 |     |
|    7 |   1001 |       |        0 |     |
|    8 |   1001 |   200 |       10 | 210 |
|    9 |   1001 |       |        0 |     |
|   10 |   1001 |       |      -50 | -50 |
|   11 |   1001 |       |        0 |     |
+------+--------+-------+----------+-----+
```

- if Begin is NULL then previous week End
- END = Begin + Increase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of window functions gets you the result. `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` is the default scope when you specify an `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause, however, as the other window function has it explicitly stated and doesn't use the default scope, I felt it was important to show; as you can see the difference.

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES ( 1,1001,100,-10),
                ( 2,1001,NULL,  0),
                ( 3,1001, 90,  0),
                ( 4,1001,NULL, 20),
                ( 5,1001,NULL,100),
                ( 6,1001,NULL,-20),
                ( 7,1001,NULL,  0),
                ( 8,1001,200, 10),
                ( 9,1001,NULL,  0),
                (10,1001,NULL,-50),
                (11,1001,NULL,  0)) V(Week, ItemNr, [Begin],Increase))
SELECT Week,
       ItemNr,
       ISNULL([Begin],S.Starting + SUM(Increase) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNr ORDER BY Week ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)) AS [Begin],
       Increase,
       S.Starting + SUM(Increase) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNr ORDER BY Week ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS [End]
FROM VTE V
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 [Begin] AS Starting
                  FROM VTE ca
                  WHERE ca.ItemNr = V.ItemNr
                  ORDER BY Week ASC) S;
```

*Note: This appears to be some kind of stock system. it's worth noting that this doesn't take into account that the stock level could go wrong. For example, say an item is stolen; the value of `[End]` and `[Begin]` (when it has a value of `NULL`) would be wrong in those events. If this needs to be taken into consideration, then we need to know this in the question.*

*Edit: Solution to cater for "lost" stock. With this, this takes the last "known" value for the stock and aggregates. So, for this example, in Week 1, although 10 items were "sold", the start of the week 2 shows the beginning value as 35. This means that 5 items are missing (stolen?). This there needs to effect all stock levels going forward. Thus you get:*

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES ( 1,1001,100,-10),
                 ( 2,1001,NULL,  0),
                 ( 3,1001, 90,  0),
                 ( 4,1001,NULL, 20),
                 ( 5,1001,NULL,100),
                 ( 6,1001,NULL,-20),
                 ( 7,1001,NULL,  0),
                 ( 8,1001,200, 10),
                 ( 9,1001,NULL,  0),
                 (10,1001,NULL,-50),
                 (11,1001,NULL,  0),
                 (1,1002,50,-10),
                 (2,1002,35,0),--Begin value lowered. Some items went "missing"
                 (3,1002,NULL,5), 
                 (4,1002,40,10)) V(Week, ItemNr, [Begin],Increase))
SELECT Week,
       ItemNr,
       [Begin],
       Increase,
       LastKnown,
       WeekKnown,
       ISNULL([Begin],S.LastKnown + SUM(Increase) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNr, WeekKnown ORDER BY Week ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)) AS ActualBegin,
       ISNULL([Begin],S.LastKnown + SUM(Increase) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNr, WeekKnown ORDER BY Week ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) AS [End]       
FROM VTE V
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 [Begin] AS LastKnown, Week AS WeekKnown
                  FROM VTE ca
                  WHERE ca.ItemNr = V.ItemNr
                    AND ca.Week <= V.Week
                    AND ca.[Begin] IS NOT NULL
                  ORDER BY Week DESC) S
ORDER BY V.ItemNr, V.Week;
```

Comment: What do you mean @Sami? That's a basic expression. From the OP's sample data it's clearly some kind of stock level, or similar. Start with 5 apples, you get 2 more, you now have 7. `End = Begin + Increase = 5 + 2 = 7`. Sell 4 the following day, and then you have `End = 7 + (-4) = 3` 7 being the value you started the day at,

Comment: thanks, this works perfectly! now for all items in db...

well spotted on "lost stock" @Larnu, there are many data issues, some in the real data set does not make sense or add up, but now we can focus on what is there and what should be there and improve transaction accuracy

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way too

```
SELECT T1.Week,
       T1.ItemNr,
       CASE WHEN T1.[Begin] IS NULL THEN
            (SELECT MAX([Begin]) + SUM(Increase) FROM @T WHERE Week < T1.Week AND ItemNr = T1.ItemNr)
            ELSE
            T1.[Begin]
       END [Begin],
       T1.Increase,
       CASE WHEN T1.[Begin] IS NULL THEN
            (SELECT MAX([Begin]) + SUM(Increase) FROM @T WHERE Week < T1.Week AND ItemNr = T1.ItemNr)
            ELSE
            T1.[Begin]
       END + T1.Increase [End]
FROM @T T1;
```

**Returns:**

```
+------+--------+-------+----------+-----+
| Week | ItemNr | Begin | Increase | End |
+------+--------+-------+----------+-----+
|    1 |   1001 |   100 |      -10 |  90 |
|    2 |   1001 |    90 |        0 |  90 |
|    3 |   1001 |    90 |        0 |  90 |
|    4 |   1001 |    90 |       20 | 110 |
|    5 |   1001 |   110 |      100 | 210 |
|    6 |   1001 |   210 |      -20 | 190 |
|    7 |   1001 |   190 |        0 | 190 |
|    8 |   1003 |   200 |       10 | 210 |
|    9 |   1003 |   210 |        0 | 210 |
|   10 |   1003 |   210 |      -50 | 160 |
|   11 |   1003 |   160 |        0 | 160 |
+------+--------+-------+----------+-----+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=eb29bfdcbada512e02733b25e1f4bb33)**